# Best logic to make dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have 9 dates with variable - effDate1, effDate2, effDate3, effDate4, effDate5, effDate6, effDate7, effDate8, effDate9.

All of the above are string in mm/dd/yyyy.

I need to convert each in date object in javascript. I have the following logic:

```
var parts = effDate1.split("/");

    var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
            parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,
            parseInt(parts[1], 10));
```

I don't want to write this code 9 times. I know I can use functions. Can you suggest how best to write it?

Comment: Write a function that get a date string as input, and output the date object.

Comment: Ehh `var date = new Date(effDate);` should parse it?

Comment: @tymeJV where I live, `'01/02/2015'` is the _1st of Feburary_, so although _Date_ may assume it's the _2nd of January_, so you shouldn't assume it will work. In fact, look at [**the spec**](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) and you'll see _"The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in [Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."_ tldr ISO8601 or parse manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them to an array and then loop through them, something like:

```
var dates = [effDate1, effDate2, effDate3, effDate4, effDate5, effDate6, effDate7, effDate8, effDate9];

for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++){
    var parts = dates[i].split("/");
    var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
            parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,
            parseInt(parts[1], 10));
}
```

Edit: as per comments, you should not use `for(var i in dates)` when iterating arrays, instead, use `for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++)` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Dont loop over arrays with `for in`, use a regular `for` loop - `for in` is for iterating over object properties.

Comment: @tymeJV Cheers, I didn't know that, I'll update answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the strings into an *Array* and a simple `for` loop will solve your problem

```
var d_strs = [effDate1, effDate2, effDate3, effDate4, effDate5, effDate6, effDate7, effDate8, effDate9],
    i, parts, dt;
for (i = 0; i < d_strs.length; ++i) {
    parts = d_strs[i].split('/');
    dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10), parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,  parseInt(parts[1], 10));
    // do something with dt
}
```

It may also be of note that your current method of creating a *Date* will do it in the client's local timezone, which may be different to the timezone you intend. If this is important, use *UTC* (or keep a record of the intended timezone's offset from UTC in minutes so adjusting for it is easier).

Answer (score 0):

As you said - use a function for it:

```
function getDate(date) 
{
  var parts = date.split("/");

  return new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
                  parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(parts[1], 10));
}

getDate(effDate1);
```